# How to make blinking animation in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create a sequence of actions to simulate eye blinking of my character but I have no idea how to properly do this. I need it to stand still for like 5 secs, then blink once and wait for 5 seconds again and loop forever. Hope someone could shed some light here.

This is what I've got so far which doesn't work to what I have expected (After 3f, it will keep blinking, how do I detect blinking animation end and reset back to stand?):

```
this.addAction( Actions.sequence(
            Actions.run( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stand();
                }
            }),
            Actions.delay(.3f), 
            Actions.run( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    blink();
                }
            })));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Libgdx` has a class `RepeatAction`, which is what you are looking for.
Basicly you need to call:

```
this.addAction(Actions.forever(Actions.sequence(
    Actions.run(new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stand();
        }
    }),
    Actions.delay(0.3f),
    Actions.run(new Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            blink();
        }
    });
)));
```

But instead of using `new Runnable` you may use one of the methods provided by `Libgdx` `Actions`.
So for example, the `stand()`, isn't it only "do nothing"? This can be achieved with an `Actions.delay(5f)`, which waits for 5 seconds.
And the `blink()` isn't it only switching from "visible" to "invisible"?
This could be don with `Actions.alpha(0, 0.2f)`, which changes the characters transparency from its current to 0 in 0.2 seconds. Then you could add another `delay` to let the character "wait" in the invisible state and make it visible again with `Actions.alpha(1, 0.2f)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I seems to get it to work but somehow the effect doesn't seems very consistent. Sometimes it blinks too fast and I have to adjust the delay() and the animation frame duration. I'm not sure now if addAction should be the appropriate way to do this but still thanks alot.

Comment: It depends, on what you want to achieve with the `Action`s. Also make sure, that the correct `delta` (`Gdx.graphics.getDelta`) is used to `update()` the `Action`s and `Animation`s.